# T-SQL CONTAINS with search condition from subquery

Tags: t-sql

I have a table containing search values and wish to use CONTAINS to search another table with those values.  The table to search contains email data.

```
SEARCHTABLE
ID     VALUE
1      '*domain1.com'
2      '*domain2.co.uk'

EMAILTABLE

ID     SENDER                 BODY
1      'fred@domain1.com'     'body text of email'
2      'frank@domain1.com'    'body text of email'
3      'bob@domain3.net'      'body text of email'
```

is there a way to build a query searching the EMAILTABLE with the values in the SEARCHTABLE in a subquery i.e. the equivalent of :

```
SELECT * FROM EMAILTABLE where CONTAINS (sender, '*domain.com OR *domain2.co.uk'
```

I'd be grateful for any assistance with this.

Comment: You need to use `LIKE` with `'%'` as a wildcard instead of `'*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
SELECT EMAILTABLE.* 
FROM EMAILTABLE 
INNER JOIN SEARCHTABLE ON  EMAILTABLE.SENDER LIKE '%'+REPLACE(SEARCHTABLE.Value,'*','')+'%'
```

Comment: perfect.   I should have figured that out myself.  Thanks for your help